# Change section command in article

Tags: titlesec, article

In the document class article how do I change the command `\section` to behave exactly like the command `\chapter` in the document class book? i.e. write Chapter # and then the title and also leave some empty space at the top of the page.

Sorry if my question is not clearly stated and if this question might already exist but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to switch to `report` or `book` if you want chapters? There are possibilities to *port* an existing document one level up.

Comment: @Johannes_B I need to stick with `article` for other reasons. What do you mean port an existing document one level up?

Comment: port up, making an already written document using sections to work with a chapter based document. As far as i know, package  coseuol` can do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a solution with titlesec package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
          {\clearpage\vspace*{50pt}%
          \normalfont\huge\bfseries}%
          {Section \thesection}%
          {20pt}%
          {\Huge}%
          [\vspace{40pt}]
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```