# 72 pt. spacing before Section heading

Tags: sectioning, margins, paragraphs, titlesec

I'm trying to add a 72 pt. space before the section heading. I do not only want the 72 pt. between paragraphs but basically every section should start at a new page with a 72 pt. spacing before it.

Preambel:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{72pt}{18pt} 
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\fontsize{16}{19}\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}  

\titlespacing{\subsection}
{0pt}{36pt}{18pt} % first paragraph should have 18 pt spacing before it
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{19}\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}
{0pt}{18pt}{18pt}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{19}\bfseries}     {\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{}
```

For example

```
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
\blindtext
\section{Section 2}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: without 72 pt. spacing]

How the 72 pt. before spacing approx. should look like on every page where a new section starts:

[image: with 72 pt. spacing]

Comment: you can see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237927/change-section-command-in-article/237934#237934

Comment: may be good answer here is `\titleformat{\section}
{\clearpage\vspace*{72pt}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}`

Comment: @touhami: Thank you very much. That works exactly as I need it!